stm32l072kz - write firmware in flash bank2 and jump to bank2
I am writing a new firmware received by UART. I use DMA with Interrupt and my new firmware is in .HEX format, I receive it in blocks of 1500 in 1500 bytes, and I have a case that performs the processing of extracting the addresses, crc, cheksum, and the real data and after that calls the businessRules_update_firmware function. I want to write the firmware using the application code itself. However, I have a problem writing after 0x08018000. My microcontroller is category 5, with 192KB and dual-bank. And my application code is running on bank1 and I want to write the new firmware on bank2. I always record correctly from 0x08018000 to 0x080180F0, but I can never record after 0x08018100, what could this be?
The businessRules_updateFirmware function is called within a loop after the data from the .HEX file has been processed.
uint32_t flashAddress = 0x08018000;

void businessRules_updateFirmware(void)
{
  uint8_t buffer[FIRMWARE_PACKAGE_SIZE];
  uint32_t pageError;

  if (protocol_feedFirmwareBuffer(buffer))
  {
    HAL_FLASH_Unlock();
    HAL_FLASH_OB_Unlock();

    __HAL_FLASH_CLEAR_FLAG(FLASH_FLAG_EOP | FLASH_FLAG_WRPERR | FLASH_FLAG_PGAERR | FLASH_FLAG_BSY);
    FLASH_EraseInitTypeDef eraseInitStruct;
    eraseInitStruct.TypeErase = FLASH_TYPEERASE_PAGES;
    eraseInitStruct.PageAddress = flashAddress;
    eraseInitStruct.NbPages = 1;

    if (HAL_FLASHEx_Erase(&eraseInitStruct, &pageError) != HAL_OK)
    {
      HAL_FLASH_Lock();
      HAL_FLASH_OB_Lock();
      return;
    }

    uint8_t binaryData[FIRMWARE_PACKAGE_SIZE / 2];

    hexStringToBytes((const char*)buffer, binaryData, FIRMWARE_PACKAGE_SIZE);

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < FIRMWARE_PACKAGE_SIZE / 2; i += 4)
    {
      uint32_t data = *(uint32_t*)&binaryData[i];

      if(HAL_FLASH_Program(FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_WORD, flashAddress , data) != HAL_OK)
      {
        HAL_FLASH_Lock();
        HAL_FLASH_OB_Lock();
        return;
      }

      flashAddress += 4;
    }

    HAL_FLASH_Lock();
    HAL_FLASH_OB_Lock();
  }
}


uint8_t hexCharToValue(char hexChar)
{
  if (isdigit(hexChar))
    return hexChar - '0';
  else
    return tolower(hexChar) - 'a' + 10;
}

void hexStringToBytes(const char *hexString, uint8_t *byteArray, size_t byteArraySize)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < byteArraySize / 2; ++i)
  {
    if (2 * i + 1 >= strlen(hexString))
    {
      byteArray[i] = 0x00;
      break;
    }

    byteArray[i] = (hexCharToValue(hexString[2 * i]) << 4) | hexCharToValue(hexString[2 * i + 1]);
  }
}

I tried some variations of this function, but without success so far.
void businessRules_updateFirmware(void)
{

    uint32_t pageAddress;
    uint32_t pageError;
    uint8_t buffer[FIRMWARE_PACKAGE_SIZE];

    bool dataIsReady = false;
    dataIsReady = protocol_feedFirmwareBuffer(buffer);

    if (dataIsReady)
    {
        uint8_t binaryData[FIRMWARE_PACKAGE_SIZE / 2];
        hexStringToBytes((char *)buffer, binaryData, FIRMWARE_PACKAGE_SIZE / 2);

        pageAddress = protocol_getAddressToFirmware();

        HAL_FLASH_Unlock();
        HAL_FLASH_OB_Unlock();


        FLASH_EraseInitTypeDef eraseInitStruct;
        eraseInitStruct.TypeErase = FLASH_TYPEERASE_PAGES;
        eraseInitStruct.PageAddress = pageAddress;
        eraseInitStruct.NbPages = 1;

        if(HAL_FLASHEx_Erase(&eraseInitStruct, &pageError) != HAL_OK){
            HAL_FLASH_Lock();
            HAL_FLASH_OB_Lock();
            return;
        }

        for(uint32_t i = 0; i < FIRMWARE_PACKAGE_SIZE / 2; i += 4){

            uint32_t data = (binaryData[i] << 0) | (binaryData[i + 1] << 8) | (binaryData[i + 2] << 16) | (binaryData[i + 3] << 24);

            if(HAL_FLASH_Program(FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_WORD, pageAddress + i , data) != HAL_OK){
                HAL_FLASH_Lock();
                HAL_FLASH_OB_Lock();
                return;
            }

        }

        pageAddress += FIRMWARE_PACKAGE_SIZE / 2;
        protocol_setAddressToFirmware(pageAddress);

        HAL_FLASH_OB_Lock();
        HAL_FLASH_Lock();
    }

}

uint8_t hexCharToValue(char hexChar) {
    if (isdigit(hexChar))
        return hexChar - '0';
    else
        return tolower(hexChar) - 'a' + 10;
}

void hexStringToBytes(const char *hexString, uint8_t *byteArray, size_t byteArraySize) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < byteArraySize; ++i) {
        byteArray[i] = (hexCharToValue(hexString[2 * i]) << 4) | hexCharToValue(hexString[2 * i + 1]);
    }
}


uint32_t data = *(uint32_t*)&binaryData[i]; Can you be sure that binaryData is properly aligned? You might make is an array of uint32_t instead. Also: "I tried some variations..." Without showing them, this sentence is completely useless.

How large is 1 page of NVM?

What is FIRMWARE_PACKAGE_SIZE?  What is the Flash page size?  Do any of the HAL function calls return errors?

"The businessRules_updateFirmware function is called within a loop after the data from the .HEX file has been processed." What exactly does that mean? You erase the same address every time that function is called. And you write to the same address in each function call. How should this work for flashing multiple 1500 byte blocks in a row? Do you update flashAddress for each block?

According to the Reference manual from this page, in 3.2 it says: "Erase operation performed by page" and Table 6 tells you that page size is 128 bytes (0x0801 8000 - 0x0801 807F 128 bytes Page 768 sector 24). That means you cannot just erase the flash using 1 address if you want to flash 1500 bytes. Also if 2 chunks of 1500 bytes share one page you need to take extra measures.

We can only help if you respond to feedback from comments and answers.

@Gerhardh, The page size is 128 Bits, FIRMWARE PACKAGE SIZE 256.
I edited the post, adding other variations.
I have a GET_FIRMWARE case, which is responsible for extracting crc, checksum, bytes, addresses from the .HEX file received by the uart. So after I receive 1500 data, they are passed into the case, and at the end of the case the businessRules_updateFirmware function is called containing the ready buffer with the real and processed data

@Gerhardh With each call to the businessRules_updateFirmware function, a new address is extracted, 0x08018000 - 0x08018080 - 0x080180100 - 0x08018180 etc..., but it only writes from 0x08018000 to 0x080180F0

@kkrambo The page size is 128 Bits, FIRMWARE PACKAGE SIZE 256, Does not return error in HAL

As most of the details are hidden from us, please edit your question to provide a MCVE. That can be some code that provides 2 hard coded set of data instead of data from UART. Then show how the function is called. It should be compilable and reproduce the issue. This is to rule out any error in the calling part.

@Gerhardh Forgive me for the delay, If I don't find the point of failure, I will organize it and try to make it clear, and share the processing code with you.

@Gerhardh But I'm almost accepting that the problem is that my full firmware package needs several cycles. As I said, I receive it every 500 bytes, and its total size is 84,000 bytes. So I believe that as my UART_TAM_BUFF_RECP = 2048, the UART is not calling my case that processes the GET_FIRMWARE data in all packets. When the pointer reaches values ​​like 2027, 2035, 2047, my GET_FIRMWARE case stops being triggered, and my UART seems to receive and ignore the data, it no longer cares about processing it.

You mentinoed 1500 bytes blocks. Neither 500, nor 1500 is close to being multiple of 256 bytes (256 hex digits, i.e. 128 bytes of data). Do you take any action to make sure you get data for one page at once and not split in 2 chunks? I would use some GPIO pins to indicate when I enter and leave flashing code and/or when UART interrupt is active.

I receive the complete 1500 or 500 byte packets, then after that the UART calls a case that does all the data processing. The case is responsible for:
Get data received in the buffer
Extract the crc
Extract the checksum
Extract the Address
Extract the real data
store the actual data in another buffer with size 256
Trigger a package complete flag
Call the businessRules_updateFirmware function.
Then the businessRules_updateFirmware function calls protocol_feedbufferfirmware which fills the buffer with the 256 bytes of data ready and returns to write to flash

This structure is inside my case
typedef enum
{
STARTER_PACKAGE,
QTD_PACKAGE,
ADDR_PACKAGE,
CMD_PACKAGE,
DATA_PACKAGE,
CS_PACKAGE
} t_protocolSavingFirmwareSteps;
typedef struct
{
uint8_t initialByte;
uint8_t quantBytes[2];
uint8_t addrBytes[4];
uint8_t initialAddrBytes[4];
uint8_t fullAddrBytes[8];
uint8_t commandBytes[2];
uint8_t dataBytes[32];
uint8_t checkSumBytes[2];
} protocol_hex_firmware_t;

Describing what you want your code to do is not useful. Show what it really does.

I solved the problem, as I was using DMA, I was having a problem with my circular buffer that was filling up and was unable to process the rest of the data received. Then I adjusted the pointer and counter and also the HAL_UARTEx_RxEventCallback function
